# How can I use If-Then statements in Snowflake - SnowSQL (Linux)

Tags: sql, linux, if-statement, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I' ve been trying to use If-Then statements in Snowflake - SnowSQL but I keep getting the error:
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'IF'.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/ksh

export SNOWSQL_USER="my_usr"
export SNOWSQL_PWD="my_pwd"
export SNOWSQL_WAREHOUSE="my_wh"
export SNOWSQL_DATABASE="my_db"
export SNOWSQL_SCHEMA="my_schm"
export SNOWSQL_ACCOUNT="my_acct"

snowsql -o echo=true -o exit_on_error=True<<EOSQL

-- create a sample table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sample_table (id INT, value INT);

-- populate the sample table
INSERT INTO sample_table VALUES (1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30);

-- use an IF statement to conditionally update the value column
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sample_table WHERE value > 25) > 0 THEN
UPDATE sample_table SET value = value * 2 WHERE value > 25;
ELSE
UPDATE sample_table SET value = value * 3;
END IF;

-- view the updated table
SELECT * FROM sample_table;


EOSQL
```

Am I missing something that's necessary for the if statement to run?
Tried to write it in a different way.. nothing. Tried to use variables.. nothing.

Comment: Try to load the SQL statements as a SQL file as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-use#running-in-a-session-source-or-load-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use [control flow constructs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/branch) like `IF-ELSE` you need Snowflake Scripting block:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN
   IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE value > 25)) THEN
     UPDATE sample_table SET value = value * 2 WHERE value > 25;
   ELSE
     UPDATE sample_table SET value = value * 3;
   END IF;
END;
$$;
```

Also:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sample_table WHERE value > 25) > 0
=> 
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE value > 25)
```

Related: [Using Snowflake Scripting in SnowSQL and the Classic Web Interface](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples)

Comment: Thank you Lukasz. Something more I noticed while trying to run a script in Linux with the above code in SnowSQL, I must use escape characters ('\') on '$' in order for it to parse properly.